# Individual pages via GitHub pages custom domain or FTP

Tags: webserver, github-pages

I manage a website which is built from a GitHub repository via an action which commits a live version to a certain branch, and then the webserver routinely checks if there are any updates on this branch and, if so, pulls them down to its `public_html` directory. This then serves the website on some domain, say
`example.com`.

For various (practically immutable) reasons, there are individual webpages that are "built" from other individual repositories — here I say "built" because these repositories are almost always just some `.html` files and such, with little post-processing, and could thus be served directly via GitHub pages. I want these to be served at `example.com/individual-page`. To achieve this, I currently have a GitHub action which transfers the files via FTP to a directory on the webserver which is symlinked inside `public_html`, thus making all the files accessible.

However, it now occurs to me that I could "simply" (assuming this is even possible — I imagine it would need some DNS tweaking) activate GitHub pages on these individual repositories, set with the custom domain `example.com`, and avoid having to pass via FTP. On one hand, it seems maybe conceptually simpler to have `public_html` on the webserver only contain the files coming from the main website build, and it would be simpler to make new standalone pages from GitHub repositories; on the other hand, it seems like maybe "everything that appears on `example.com` should be found in the same directory" is a good idea.

> **What (if any) is the recommended best practice here: to have these individual pages managed by GitHub pages with custom domains (since they are basically just web previews of the contents of the repositories), or to continue to transfer everything over to the webserver in one directory?**

> In other words maybe, **is it a "good idea" to *partially* host your website with GitHub pages? Is this even possible with the right DNS settings?**

*(I must admit, I don't really understand what exactly my browser does when I navigate to `example.com/individual-page`, and what would happen if such a directory existed in my webserver and also GitHub pages was trying to serve up a webpage at this same address, so I guess bonus points if you want to explain the basics!)*

Answer (score 2):

The DNS option you describe doesn't work for pages.

While you can use a CNAME record to point your domain to another domain or an A record to point your domain to an IP address, DNS doesn't handle individual pages (as in example.com/a). It would work if each page was, for instance, a.example.com, but that's not a page, it's a whole different website.

What you can do, however, is [include those other repositories as submodules of your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/using-submodules-with-github-pages), and then everything works without any DNS magic (except the simple CNAME record, which isn't magic).

It would be a good idea to implement this described solution, as it's the simplest. In any case, as long as your current solution works automatically without issues and the hosting cost isn't an issue, I don't see any need to take the time to implement a new solution.

If you want to only serve some files or pages from the submodules, you can have build actions and [serve a specific directory](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22324).

> I must admit, I don't really understand what exactly my browser does when I navigate to example.com/individual-page

Your browser requests the DNS records of your domain (example.com), in this case the A record (since this is the root domain). This A record gives an IP address, which your browser uses to request the page. As you can see, pages aren't handled by DNS at all.

That means only one machine handles all requests for a domain (which doesn't mean it can't delegate some pages to another machine, but that's more complex). That means it's impossible to have "directory conflicts", because either your server handles the request or GitHub does. Your browser doesn't check if the page exists at server A and if not, if it exists at server B.

Comment: this is a perfect answer, thank you! I'd also read about submodules at some point and remember being a bit hesitant, but they actually seem pretty perfect for exactly this use case, so I'll look into them now :-)